# How to merge all directories on multiple levels?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I am on Mac Os 10.14.6 and have a directory that multiple levels of subdirectories each which contain files.

e.g.
[image]

Using the terminal, I would like to merge them all into one directory (so I am only left with the files but no folders). 
I would like a single command that can work on multiple different directories (regardless of name). Hence, the command cannot specify directory names.

How can I do this?

---

**Steps I have tried**

Googling around, it sounds like the `mv` command is perfect. So I tried this:

```
mv */*
```

However, that only merges one level down. e.g.:

[image]

How can I get it to go through all the levels. Also, is there away to optionally automatically delete the empty directories? (By optionally, I mean that I can omit that part off the command, when I do not when the empty directories deleted, so the empty directories remain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `find`, like

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" .' sh {} +
```

And to delete leftover directories, use

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/root/directory -type f -exec mv {} /path/to/destination/folder/ \;
```

- `find`: The command used to search for files and directories within a
  specified location.
- `/path/to/root/directory`: Replace this with the
  actual path to your root directory where the subdirectories are
  located.
- `-type f`: Specifies that we are looking for regular files (not directories).
- `-exec mv {} /path/to/destination/folder/ \;`: Executes the mv command on each found file ({}). It moves (mv) each file to the specified
  destination folder (/path/to/destination/folder/).